# how to find cluster id of my hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy data from AWS S3 to my hadoop cluster. While researching about copying the data, I found [S3DistCp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html). While reading about it, I came across cluster id term. I read about cluster id from [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html), but couldn't identify how to get cluster id of my hadoop cluster.

Where can I find my hadoop cluster's cluster id?

**Note:** I'm using Horton Works 2.2 cluster setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose, your `dfs.namenode.name.dir` location points to `/hadoop/hdfs/namenode`.

Your hadoop cluster ID will be in this file `/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/VERSION`.

Open the `VERSION` file in text editor and search for `namespaceID`. The namespaceID in the VERSION file is your hadoop cluster ID.

You can also find your `namespaceID` in `/hadoop/hdfs/namesecondary/current/VERSION` file.

Good Luck!!!!

Comment: I tried looking for that file, but couldn't find it. what is the default path for `dfs.name.dir`? Maybe I can look into it

Comment: `dfs.name.dir` is not present. Did you meant `dfs.namenode.name.dir`?

Comment: Sorry for mentioning `dfs.name.dir`. The correct format is `dfs.namenode.name.dir`. What does it point to?

Comment: It is pointing to `/hadoop/hdfs/namenode`, but when I do `cd /hadoop/hdfs/namenode`, terminal says `-bash: cd: /hadoop/hdfs/namenode: No such file or directory`. Now, how do I proceed? :|

Comment: Try stopping your hadoop cluster and `create the folder manually`(Give 777 permissions if necessary). Now start your hadoop cluster again. It should have the folder `/current` in it.

Comment: Can't do that :| It is used by my team :). Any other way?

Comment: Is your system `"Master Node"`? If yes, `cd /hadoop/hdfs/namenode` should have worked. If no, go to your master node to find your `namespaceID` or simply `ssh` it (if you have permission)

Comment: I assume, when you say `master node` you meant `name node`. Yup, it is master node. It didn't worked :| Btw, I don't have root permissions!

Comment: If you are logged in as hadoop user in your namenode system, can you post the result of `ls -l /hadoop` and `ls -l /hadoop/hdfs`? If this path does not exists, then create it manually. (This should have been done before starting hadoop cluster)

Comment: `ls -l /hadoop/hdfs` resulted `namesecondary`  and `ls -l /hadoop` resulted  in `falcon`, `hbase`, `hdfs` and `zookeeper`.

Comment: Can you post your hadoop configuration files contents in your question?

Comment: Where can I find all the configuration files & what are they? btw, I'm using Horton works 2.2.

Comment: Post the contents of `hdfs-site.xml` and `hadoop-env.sh` in your hadoop configuration directory (Mostly in `$HADOOP_HOME/conf` or `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop`)

Comment: done! Removed ip and port for security reasons from config files

Comment: Configuration looks good. Maybe you have missed something in `Create Directories` step while installation. Refer this: [http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.10/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap2-4.html]

Comment: Try this in terminal, `find / -type f -name "VERSION"`. `"/"` searches whole filesystem, `"."` searches current directory. (Replace `/` with `.` if u want to narrow down your search)

Comment: Everything is working fine in my HDP. So, I don't think we missed anything :).`Find` is returning more than 1000 results!! Any specific directory you want me to look into?

Comment: Previously you said, you get `namesecondary` when you type `ls -l /hadoop/hdfs`. There will be a `VERSION` file in `/hadoop/hdfs/namesecondary/current` folder. It will also contain `namespaceID`. Try it.

Comment: got it! Thanks a lot. I've removed config files, as my teammates said me not disclose the configs to outside world :)