# Hadoop 2.9.0 Incompatible cluster id

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to use Hadoop 2.9.0 in the Pseudo-Distributed mode using [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation) tutorial. The datanode is not starting and the log file shows that the error that incompatible clusterIDs for name node and data node. I found several StackOverflow answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521474/hadoop-hdfs-formatting-gets-error-failed-for-block-pool) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025221/how-to-find-cluster-id-of-my-hadoop-cluster) on the issue. All the answers suggested that change the *clusterId* in the VERSION file shown in the log file(I am pasting the relevant content of log file below.) However, when I read the VERSION files I found that the clusterId in them is same in all the 3 and is totally different in what the error log file is showing. Any idea what is going on? Please comment if you need any additional information.

Below is the content of the error log-file:

```
2018-02-17 21:58:00,465 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Using 1 threads to upgrade data directories (dfs.datanode.parallel.volumes.load.threads.num=1, dataDirs=1)
2018-02-17 21:58:00,499 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /tmp/hadoop-uname/dfs/data/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 24965@mname.host.edu
2018-02-17 21:58:00,503 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Failed to add storage directory [DISK]file:/tmp/hadoop-uname/dfs/data/
java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /tmp/hadoop-uname/dfs/data: namenode clusterID = CID-08ce647c-0922-4da6-accb-15620161d0b0; datanode clusterID = CID-130d222c-d2cf-4509-bde4-e58637bf9b0c
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:760)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.loadStorageDirectory(DataStorage.java:293)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.loadDataStorage(DataStorage.java:409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.addStorageLocations(DataStorage.java:388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:556)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1649)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1610)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:816)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-02-17 21:58:00,510 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid c8b193d5-50e2-4983-8831-a5ce4820e58f) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Exiting. 
java.io.IOException: All specified directories have failed to load.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1649)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1610)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:816)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-02-17 21:58:00,510 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid c8b193d5-50e2-4983-8831-a5ce4820e58f) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
```

Below is the content of /tmp/hadoop-uname/dfs/data/current/VERSION

```
#Sun Feb 18 18:07:28 2018
storageID=DS-c1c0868c-4ce0-45bf-8e76-4223d46587b1
clusterID=CID-0b9a5a3e-dbf0-4a36-aab1-f72e4a1e6993
cTime=0
datanodeUuid=ad38f7c2-f4ac-466f-8330-f06488df73f8
storageType=DATA_NODE
layoutVersion=-57
```

Below is the content of /tmp/hadoop-uname/dfs/name/current/VERSION

```
#Sun Feb 18 18:04:19 2018
namespaceID=1735122419
clusterID=CID-0b9a5a3e-dbf0-4a36-aab1-f72e4a1e6993
cTime=1518995059388
storageType=NAME_NODE
blockpoolID=BP-1715794989-127.0.1.1-1518995059388
layoutVersion=-63
```

Below is the content of /tmp/hadoop-uname/dfs/namesecondary/current/VERSION

```
#Sun Feb 18 17:46:57 2018
namespaceID=1735122419
clusterID=CID-0b9a5a3e-dbf0-4a36-aab1-f72e4a1e6993
cTime=1518992971549
storageType=NAME_NODE
blockpoolID=BP-2107146081-127.0.1.1-1518992971549
layoutVersion=-63
```

And this is how etc/hdfs-site.xml looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
                <value>1</value>
                    </property>
</configuration>
```